# Confusion regarding transversal for a partition in Smith Introductory Mathematics: Algebra and Analysis

Tags: combinatorics, relations

In Smith's *Introductory Mathematics: Algebra and Analysis*, I came across the definition of a *transversal* for a partition along with examples. Either I don't understand one of the examples, or it is simply wrong. Since I haven't authored any mathematics textbooks, I tend to think it's the former. Can someone clarify?

Here's the quote from the book:

> Finally, when you have a partition of a set $S$, it is often useful to
>   have one representative from each set comprising the partition. A set
>   of these representatives is called a *transversal* for the partition.
>   [...] We view a plane as a set, the elements of which are the
>   geometric points comprising the plane. The plane can be partitioned
>   into parallel straight lines, and then any straight line which is skew
>   to the lines in the partition will suffice as a transversal. Such a
>   skew straight line will intersect each of the family of parallel lines
>   in exactly one point, as required. One could think of crazy
>   transversals, where a point is selected from each of the family of
>   parallel lines in some fashion, but our transversal has the virtue of
>   being geometrically pleasant.

Here's my thoughts.

1. Let $L$ be the set of lines in the plane. There is an equivalence relation $\parallel \> : L \times L$ (does that functional notation properly describe relations, too?) on $L$. It gives rise to a partition of the set of lines into parallel lines, but I'm dubious that it partitions the plane because any point in the plane, say $(0,0)$, will be on infinitely many lines.
2. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_%28combinatorics%29) agrees that a *transversal* "is a set containing exactly one element from each member of the collection". It seems to me that if the collection in question is a partition of lines in the plane into (disjoint) sets of parallel lines, then an element of a member of the collection must be a line (i.e. an element of $L$ and *not* an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$). So if, as stated above, "a skew straight line will intersect each of the family of parallel lines in exactly one point" then I don't see how it is a transversal for the partition.
3. Based on my understanding, I propose that a transversal of the partition induced by $\parallel$ on lines in the plane is the set of lines in the plane through a given point, say $(0,0)$.

FYI, this is self-study not homework. Feel free to edit the tags if something is more appropriate.

Comment: I believe the author is saying to take the family of all lines in the plane which are parallel to a given line. This will form a partition of the plane.  Then if we take any other line, it will intersect each of the parallel lines in a point; and this set of points forms a transversal for the partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a minor notational point: no, the notation $\|:L\times L$ is not correct. Just say that the relation of being parallel is an equivalence relation on $L$. (Formally it’s a subset of $L\times L$ with certain properties.)

I suspect that you’re thinking of the partition of $L$ into equivalence classes of the relation $\|$; this is not what the author is talking about. He’s pointing out that each individual equivalence class of $\|$ is a partition of the plane into parallel lines.

If $\ell\in L$, let $[\ell]$ be the equivalence class of $\ell$, i.e., the set of all lines in the plane that are parallel to $\ell$. What the author is saying is that for each $\ell\in L$, the equivalence class $[\ell]$ is a partition of the plane. For example, for each $r\in\Bbb R$ let $\ell_r$ be the line whose equation is $x=r$, the set of all points $\langle r,y\rangle$ with first coordinate $r$. (E.g., $\ell_0$ is the $y$-axis.) Then $\{\ell_r:r\in\Bbb R\}$ is one of the equivalence classes: for each $t\in\Bbb R$, $[\ell_t]=\{\ell_r:r\in\Bbb R\}$. And as you can see, this family is a partition of the plane: if $\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2$, $\ell_x$ is the unique member of the family containing $\langle x,y\rangle$.

What does a transversal for this partition look like? Since the members of $\{\ell_r:r\in\Bbb R\}$ are the lines parallel to the $y$-axis, a transversal for this partition is a subset $T$ of the plane that contains exactly one point on each line parallel to the $y$-axis. This means that for each $x\in\Bbb R$ there is exactly one $y_x\in\Bbb R$ such that $\langle x,y_x\rangle\in T$. This is actually a very familiar idea: **this just says that** $T$ **is the graph of a function** $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ **given by** $f(x)=y_x$. The graph of the function $f(x)=x^2$, for instance, is a transversal for this partition. So is the graph of $f(x)=2x$, or $f(x)=-3x+7$.

The last two graphs, of course, are straight lines that are skew to the parallel lines of the partition: the lines forming the partition are vertical, and the lines $y=2x$ and $y=-3x+7$ are not. Any non-vertical line in the plane — i.e., any line skew to the family of parallel vertical lines — has an equation of the form $y=ax+b$. For each value of $x$, that equation picks out a unique $y_x$, namely, the real number $ax+b$. In other words, for each $x$ the equation $y=ax+b$ picks out exactly one element of $\ell_x$, so its graph is a transversal for the partition $\{\ell_r:r\in\Bbb R\}$. This is what the author is getting at when he says that any straight line skew to the members of the partition is a transversal for it. But as we saw in the previous paragraph, the graph of **every** function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a transversal for this particular partition, and most of these graphs are geometrically much less pleasant than a simple straight line.

In the foregoing discussion I worked with just one of the equivalence classes of the relation $\|$, the one consisting of the lines parallel to the $y$-axes, because it’s the easiest one to visualize and talk about. The other equivalence classes behave similarly, however.

Let me conclude by giving a complete enumeration of the equivalence classes of the relation $\|$. It’s convenient to change notation, however: for each $\theta\in[0,\pi)$ let $\ell_\theta$ be the line through the origin at an angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis. Every point in the plane except the origin is on exactly one of these lines. Then $[\ell_\theta]$, the equivalence class of $\ell_\theta$, is the set of all lines in the plane parallel to $\ell_\theta$. If $\theta=\frac{\pi}4$, for instance, these are the lines with slope $1$, the lines whose equations are of the form $y=x+a$.

> More generally, if $\theta\ne\frac{\pi}2$, then $[\ell_\theta]$ is the family of lines with slope $\tan\theta$, the lines whose equations are of the form $y=(\tan\theta)x+a$; if $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$, they are the vertical lines, the lines whose equations are of the form $x=a$.

Every line in the plane is parallel to exactly one of the $\ell_\theta$ with $0\le\theta<\pi$, so $\{[\ell_\theta]:0\le\theta<\pi\}$ is a complete enumeration of the set of equivalence classes of $\|$.

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough answer! In the prior section of the text, the author uses $\parallel$ as an example of an equivalence relation. I guess I didn't read carefully and assumed that he was referring to that same relation in the excerpt above, which gives the example of a transversal. After seeing your answer and the comment from @user84413, I re-read the section on its own. I am now certain that you are correct and the author is referring to the partition you've indicated.

Comment: @Joe: You’re very welcome.